# Access input field value in other component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this structure navbar component and form component

[image]

I have `navbar component` initially i load the user data in component from id that we store in session, in right side component we have one searchable field when i select its option i call one method that returns the updated id, and i want to show new result in the navbar based on updated `id` but i am not able to get how i will pass the updated id to navbar component, Any suggestions Thanks

Comment: @Drenai Yes i know Angular Services but don't have much idea about Observables and Behavioural Subject Can you please suggest some solution or provide some link values must be of array or object type that will be shown in left sidebar

Comment: You can always go here and read up on subjects: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects

Comment: @MikkelChristensen Will i have to use Subject, Observer or Behaviour subject

Comment: You can set query param from one component and read it from second component

Answer (score 0):

dataService.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';  
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';  
  
@Injectable({  
  providedIn: 'root'  
})  
export class DataSharingService {  
  
  SharingData = new Subject();  
  constructor() { }  
}
```

Component1.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';  
import { DataSharingService } from '../data-sharing.service';  
  
@Component({  
  selector: 'app-component1',  
  templateUrl: './component1.component.html',  
  styleUrls: ['./component1.component.css']  
})  
export class Component1Component {  
  
  Component1Data: any = '';  
  
  constructor(private DataSharing: DataSharingService) {  
    this.DataSharing.SharingData.subscribe((res: any) => {  
      this.Component1Data = res;  
    })  
  }  
  
  onSubmit(data) {  
    this.DataSharing.SharingData.next(data.value);  
  }  
}
```

Component2.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';  
import { DataSharingService } from '../data-sharing.service';  
  
@Component({  
  selector: 'app-component2',  
  templateUrl: './component2.component.html',  
  styleUrls: ['./component2.component.css']  
})  
export class Component2Component {  
  Component2Data: any = '';  
  
  
  constructor(private DataSharing: DataSharingService) {  
    this.DataSharing.SharingData.subscribe((res: any) => {  
      this.Component2Data = res;  
    })  
  }  
  
  onSubmit(data) {  
    this.DataSharing.SharingData.next(data.value);  
  }  
}
```

Component3.component.ts.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';  
import { DataSharingService } from '../data-sharing.service';  
  
@Component({  
  selector: 'app-component3',  
  templateUrl: './component3.component.html',  
  styleUrls: ['./component3.component.css']  
})  
export class Component3Component {  
  
  Component3Data: any = '';  
  
  constructor(private DataSharing: DataSharingService) {  
    this.DataSharing.SharingData.subscribe((res: any) => {  
      this.Component3Data = res;  
    })  
  }  
  
  onSubmit(data) {  
    this.DataSharing.SharingData.next(data.value);  
  }  
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks in which component should i fetch initial data in left navbar or right component, new id is being fetched inside right component

Comment: this.DataSharing.SharingData.subscribe((res: any) => {  
      this.Component3Data = res;  
    })

using the above code you will get value once it is updated.
------------------------------------------

this.DataSharing.SharingData.next(data.value); 

using above code you can update the value.

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by [Hitesh Thakor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5710473/hitesh-thakor) is a way to handle and secod way is @Input()
from navbar component to Form Component and when you change its value from navbar component then you can listen that in ngOnChanges() lifecycle in form component and show the view for that ID .

Hope you Understand